# Deduping tools crashing test classes

Tags: managed-package, leads

Recently our company has bought an AppExchange product for deduping our leads before they get into Lead object.

Several of our test classes started to fail with "DUPLICATE_RECORD" "Duplicate_Value" error upon further investigation it is found that the AppExchange product is enforcing the restriction.

Is there an strategy to handle this scenario (test classes getting broken because of restriction enforced by installed packages) ?

Comment: If you do not want duplicate leads in your system then the tests should follow that. Seems to me like the tests are working just fine (failing as they should). Time to revisit them and update accordingly Restrictions are due to your business requirements, the package is just doing what you tell it to do (unless it is not configurable).

Answer (score 1):

For this, you will need to edit your test classes to make test records unique within the given test. If I create multiple records of the same type in the same test class, I put a number after their name and variable. First, it helps me know which one I am referring to. But, it also helps prevent this issue on my end.